# Google Play Console showing incorrect data since may 7 in all apps

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play, google-play-console

Since may 7, `Google Play Console` is showing incorrect data in all my apps

I can't find anything in google about this. Maybe it's a general problem? Or what happens?

In the picture you can see that since may 7, `new users acquired` and `users lost` are displaying very abnormal low data, from 500 to 10-20. **And that is happening in all my apps**, not only in this app.

[image]

Also in statistics screen, I can see how new users acquisitions are 20-25 since may 7, and before may 7 were 450-500.

Comment: please guy, can you check your accounts and tell me if you have incorrect values like me?

Comment: From my experience the statistics in the Play Console are unreliable for the last few days. May 7th is just 2 days ago, so i wouldn't worry too much.

Comment: @einUsername can you check your data please?

Answer (score 3):

It's exactly like this for me too right now. For the past couple weeks shows really low installs the day before, then corrects later in the day. This time it's two days in a row.

I've seen this many times in my years using the console, it frequently has this problem. Bottom line is, don't freak out.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently nothing has changed. Even now, the data seems inaccurate. Too much fluctuation.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33813591)